# Installing pywin32

Tags: python-2.7, pywin32, easy-install

I have issues with installing pywin32 on my machine. I am using `easy_install python` and this is the log I get.

I apologize in advance for having posted the entire log although only a segment of it is required to analyze the problem.

```
Downloading
http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/Build%20218/py
win32-218.zip/download

Processing pywin32-218.zip

Writing
c:\users\jugesh\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-o_rxio\pywin32-218\setup
.cfg

Running pywin32-218\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir
c:\users\jugesh\appdata\loc
al\temp\easy_install-o_rxio\pywin32-218\egg-dist-tmp-25h0eo

Building pywin32 2.7.218.0

Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Python27\Scripts\easy_install-script.py", line 9, in <module>
     load_entry_point('setuptools==0.8', 'console_scripts', 'easy_install')()
 File "build\bdist.win32\egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1992,
 in  main
 File "build\bdist.win32\egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1979,
 in  with_ei_usage
 File "build\bdist.win32\egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1996,
 in  <lambda>
 File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\core.py", line 152, in setup
     dist.run_commands()
 File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
     self.run_command(cmd
 File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
     cmd_obj.run()
 File "build\bdist.win32\egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 380,
 in run
 File "build\bdist.win32\egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 623,
 in easy_install
 File "build\bdist.win32\egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 653,
 in install_item
 File "build\bdist.win32\egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 849,
 in install_eggs
 File "build\bdist.win32\egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1130,
 in  build_and_install
 File "build\bdist.win32\egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1115,
 in  run_setup
 File "build\bdist.win32\egg\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 69, in run_setup
 File "build\bdist.win32\egg\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 120, in run
 File "build\bdist.win32\egg\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 71, in <lambda>  
 File "setup.py", line 1957, in <module>
 File "setup.py", line 605, in __init__
 File "C:\Python27\Lib\ntpath.py", line 96, in join
    assert len(path) > 0
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

Comment: you should apologize for posting the traceback messed up like that !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of using `easy_install`, you can try with the [Windows binaries for Pywin32](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pywin32) that are available on [Christoph Gohlke's website](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/).

Comment: Using binaries helps a lot. +1 for the answer.